# Product attribute update que stock

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-attribute, cron

I was trying to do a mass update to add products to a specific store view in a Magento enterprise cloud 2.3.4 website. However, now I am just getting the below message on the top of all admin panel screens and not sure how to get it to complete? Do I put a project on production mode and manually run the index command ??

Or
Task "Update attributes for 622 selected products": 7 item(s) have been scheduled for an update.

Comment: Please run this command 
 `php bin/magento  queue:consumers:start product_action_attribute.update`

Comment: Check if cron is properly configured, also check queue consumers as per @Shankar reply

Answer (score 1):

Check if Magento cronjobs are configured.

```
crontab -e
```

If not, install it with below command and recheck.

```
bin/magento cron:install
```

Wait at least couple of minutes. It should be processed automatically from now on.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Cron:** Check is cron installed with the command `crontab -l` to list the generated cron. In another way, try `bin/magento cron:install` it will show whether it is already generated or just now generated.
2. **Issue possibilities:** If the update attributes are performed before cron schedule then installing the cron and making it run with the command `bin/magento cron:run` now won't help in major cases. There may be a chance, the operation is not performed yet due to an indexer issue.
3. **Indexer:** Please check the indexer status with command `bin/magento indexer:status`. If it shows no backlogs but still the update attributes message is showing then run command `bin/magento indexer:reindex` and after that `bin/magento cron:run` to make sure it always runs hereafter. Then do the cache flush with the command `bin/magento cache:flush`

**Note:** If indexer reindexes failed or shown some error. Try to reset the indexer and then reindex with command `bin/magento indexer:reset && bin/magento indexer:reindex`. If it didn't solve then you may need to resolve the issue or please provide more details on the upcoming issue.

Answer (score 0):

For all the Magento installations with versions greater than 2.3.2, all the mass actions now are run during cron run to reduce the load on the live website during busy hours.

So, if you want to trigger the mass action right now, you can trigger the cron manually using the following command;

```
bin/magento cron:run
```

Answer (score 0):

For process this queue, execute  `bin/magento product_action_attribute.website.update` in magento root.

Configure RabbitMQ for automating the queue process in Magento.

Ref :
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/mq/rabbitmq-overview.html
https://www.dckap.com/blog/rabbitmq-configuration-with-magento2/